# Error building apk using Flutter Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

Using the latest version of Firebase for Flutter and tried running the application. but unfortunately having a load of errors which makes no sense to me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggbZi.png, https://gofile.io/d/b6RmlQ, https://gofile.io/d/FZBg2O, https://gofile.io/d/yCRUcy

Answer (score 0):

The flutter Firebase implementations uses native code under the hood. The errors are stating that the native classes are not found.

This is likely because of a dependency missing.

Try to `flutter clean` then `flutter pub get` and check if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work. I have tried Invalidate/Restart as well. Nothing seems to fix this issue.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions? You need to add some code in the `build.gradle` and `Application.java` https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/android

Comment: If it keeps failing, could you provide your `pubspec.yml`, `build.gradle` and `Application.java` code?

Comment: The add uploads should help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code directly there. It is better to help you that way and makes sure the images don't get lost in time.

Comment: Also: there are two `build.gradle` files. Please provide both.

Comment: Done. Can you give it a check, please?

Comment: I meant, paste the code *inside* the question, not as an external link

Comment: The Application.java is missing